# Managing multiple passwords

Tags: password-management

As a data center manager there are multiple user accounts for various systems that have to be managed. For example the root passwords for linux servers, administrative passwords for windows servers etc. What will be the best and mos secure way to maintain a database of these passwords? Should we look at Password Management Softwares?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Keepass](http://keepass.info/) for this. As you work in a datacenter, management might want you to print out the main passwords and put them in a safe. Make rules about where you keep this keepass database, who has copies, who has access, how to backup etc.

Comment: Any other password managers that I should look into. Password Manager Pro and LastPass seem good options from enterprise point of view.

Comment: I have used Lastpass in the past. I stopped after the 3.0 update, because they used such intrusive CSS and Javascript to insert their menu's in website forms. But you can do without the browser integration. And they have great sharing options. I don't know PMP.

Comment: Manager software is the option here. However, in the enterprise environment you'll need to make sure to check if the software you choose has different licensing for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

I use **Roboform**. And it's really useful and wonderful. But I want to remind a disadvantage. Once I upgrade my browser (Google Chrome), this Roboform disappear from it. Even I reinstall Roboform, the passwords can't go back. So if you want to consider this password manager, please keep this troubleshoot in mind and avoid of upgrading your browser. (I have checked, this disappearance occurred in other browser like Firefox and Opera.)

Anyway, Roboform is recommended for you.